# Convert Date to Datetime Formula

Tags: formula, datetime, date

I need to convert the following formula to DateTime based. Can you assist?

IF(C1_Date__c =  TODAY()-1, 1, 0) +
IF(C2_Date__c =  TODAY()-1, 1, 0) +
IF(C3_Date__c =  TODAY()-1, 1, 0) +
IF(C4_Date__c =  TODAY()-1, 1, 0) +
IF(C5_Date__c =  TODAY()-1, 1, 0) +
IF(C6_Date__c =  TODAY()-1, 1, 0) +
IF(C7_Date__c =  TODAY()-1, 1, 0) +
IF(C8_Date__c =  TODAY()-1, 1, 0) +
IF(C9_Date__c =  TODAY()-1, 1, 0) +
IF(C10_Date__c =  TODAY()-1, 1, 0)

Comment: Is the C1_Date__c (or the other fields similar to this) a date/time field or just a date field?  If they are, you can then sub TODAY() with NOW() as that's the date/time value where TODAY() is just a date value.

Comment: They are now DateTime values, but were Date values. I've changed all of the Field Types and need to make sure to adjust this formula accordingly where I only need the Date. Thank you.